# This model of a D-Flip flop with Enable not working as expected

Tags: verilog, flipflop, modelsim, testbench

This is a Verilog model of an array of D flip-flops with enable line along with a test bench used in ModelSim Altera:

```
module Register_Design #(parameter Width = 4)
(
    input Clock, Reset, Load, 
    input  [Width - 1:0] In,
    output reg [Width - 1:0] D
);
    always @(posedge Clock or negedge Reset) begin
        if(~Reset)
            D <= 0;
        else if(Load)
            D <= In;
    end
endmodule

module Register_Design_Test;
    reg Clock, Reset, Load;
    reg [3:0] In;
    wire [3:0] D;

    Register_Design #(4) REG0 (Clock, Reset, Load, In, D);

    initial fork
        Clock = 1'b0;
        Reset = 1'b1;
        Load  = 1'b1;
        In    = 4'h0;
        #2 Reset = 1'b0;
        #10 In = 4'b0010;
        #20 In = 4'b0100;
        #30 In = 4'b1000;
        #40 In = 4'b1100;
        #40 Load = 1'b1;
        #50 In = 4'b1111;
        #70 In = 4'b1110;
        #80 In = 4'b1100;
        #90 In = 4'b1000;
        #100 In = 4'b0000;
    join

    always @(Clock) #10 Clock <= ~Clock;

    initial #500 $stop;
endmodule
```

Here is a picture of the simulation output:
[image]

As you can see despite the `Load` input is being `1` which should load a new value into the D flip-flops, the output is always `0000` which is the default state at reset. What am I missing here?

Instead of using a behavioral dataflow model, I used this one and it worked just fine:

```
D_FF D0 (Clock, Reset, M[0], D[0]);
D_FF D1 (Clock, Reset, M[1], D[1]);
D_FF D2 (Clock, Reset, M[2], D[2]);
D_FF D3 (Clock, Reset, M[3], D[3]);

MUX_2x1 MUX0 ({In[0], D[0]}, Load, M[0]);
MUX_2x1 MUX1 ({In[1], D[1]}, Load, M[1]);
MUX_2x1 MUX2 ({In[2], D[2]}, Load, M[2]);
MUX_2x1 MUX3 ({In[3], D[3]}, Load, M[3]);

module MUX_2x1 (In, S, Out);
    input  S;
    input  [1:0] In;
    output reg Out;

    always @(*) begin
        case (S)
            1'b0:    Out = In[0];
            1'b1:    Out = In[1];
            default: Out = 1'bx;
        endcase
    end
endmodule

module D_FF (clk, reset, d, q);
    input d, clk, reset;
    output reg q;

    always @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if(reset)
            q <= 0;
        else
            q <= d;
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first code sample, you have a low active reset (`if (~Reset) D <= 0`). And in the testbench you hold `Reset` low for most of the simulation. As expected this results in `D` being 0.

In your second code sample you have a high-active reset (`if (reset) q <= 0` ) which will naturally behave differently.